# How to store small amounts of data for frequent lookup in android?

Tags: android, storing-data

I have the following data tuple describing the user of my application:

```
(userID, name, email, contact number)
```

and I want to access this data frequently throughout my application. I have a contacts table in my database in which tuples of this type are stored to describe **other** contacts. The reason I don't want to store the tuple describing the user is because it seems wasteful to have an attribute to mark which data is "self", and also I use the table directly for *inviting* users, so I don't want users to see themselves on the list of contacts! I thought about using shared preferences to store "self", but I may decide to include more data in the future, and piecing together a tuple from several key:value lookups seems like a very messy solution. What's the best way to store these "shards" of data so they're easily accessible and not wasteful?

Thank you :)

Comment: Does this data need to persist across application instances?

Comment: Yes, the data is often used as a "signature", for example when the user posts data this tuple will be tied to the information so other user's applications can connect the user to a contact in their phonebook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try Shared Preferences

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: This is going to be the simplest to implement, if you want to improve ease of retrieval, you could wrap it up in a class with accessors.

Comment: That's a good point @Rob, I was hoping that there was a simpler approach because I don't want to have to maintain a wrapper class, but it seems the simplest option so far.

Comment: @PurpleBlur if the answer helped u just marked it as best answer, Thank You

Comment: @MustafaIbrahim, I want to give other people a chance to respond, I think it's unfair to mark your answer correct so quickly because I did say I didn't want to use shared preferences in my questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here are your choices for storing data:

[Android Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

I would try using the external file if you don't want to use shared preferences or a database.  XML and JSON files are both good choices that can be easily parsed.  If you try a JSON file you could access it using [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) in your code.

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to create a subclass of Application which has fields (and get/set methods) for your variables. Use this class in your `<application>` tag in the manifest. Then use e.g. `((MyApplication)getApplicationContext()).getUserId()`

If the fields are static you might find they persist across application instances. I haven't tried this though.

Comment: I like this approach, but the data isn't determined until the application runs for the first time and establishes a connection to the server, so I would then need to retain the data somehow so the application doesn't have to wait for the server every time it's started.